# Placing a block in a given world and BlockPos

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

So I'm working on my first mod and I have an idea for a block that is actually two blocks tall. I managed to implement it successfully and the block itself works completly fine. The only problem is that there is a very noticable shadow on the top half of the block that I can't get rid of. My idea was to seperate the on block into two and when the bottom block is placed it automatically places the top half on top of itself. Thing is I can't seem to find a method how I can place a block from code.

Regards, f4ls3

Answer (score -1):

I haven't modded anything past Minecraft 1.11.2, but there were two methods to place blocks for that version.

Easy:

Get a reference to the MinecraftServer for the world you are in and do a

```
    server.commandManager.executeCommand(server, "setblock x y z blockname");
```

or

Harder

Define a blockstate:

```
    IBlockState block = ForgeRegistries.BLOCKS.getValue( new ResourceLocation("minecraft", theblockname ) ).getDefaultState();
```

For Modded Blocks:

```
    IBlockState block = ForgeRegistries.BLOCKS.getValue( new ResourceLocation("yourmodsname", theblockname ) ).getDefaultState();
```

then get a reference to the world you are in and do a:

```
    world.setBlockState( new BlockPos(x,y,z), block);
```

Comment: The "easy" way you mention is atrociously bad, and the "hard" way is overcomplicated for vanilla blocks (they have constants so you don't need to look them up by name).

Comment: Maybe offer some alternatives? What if he is placing modded blocks not vanilla ones. I've used both of these with success, if you have some hints about performance or perfect syntax please share your great wisdom.

Comment: I am indeed using a modded block. I'd preferably get rid of the shadow on the block